# How can I iterate through an array in rails view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-2, mysql2

I did a query in MySql but is working in Rails and mysql2 gem.

Here is the information:

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9adb8/6
```

The query is working fine without problems and showing this result:

```
 UNIT  V1  A1  N1   V2 A2  N2   V3  A3  N3   V4  A4  N4   V5  A5  N5
 LIFE  2   0   0    1   2  0    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
 ROB   0   1   0    0   1  2    0   0   0     0   0   0   0    0   0
```

-Installed mysql2 gem for rails 2.3.8

```
gem install mysql2 -v0.2.6
```

-Created the controller:

```
class PolicyController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @result =  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',group_concat(concat('SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),' FROM cia_ensures ce LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id  INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id AND ca.id=1  Group by p.policy_business_unit_id') from cia_ensures where id in(1,2,3,4,5);")
      @result2 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("prepare stmt from @sql;")
      @result3 = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("execute stmt;")
   end

end
```

Here is the log:

```
SQL (0.9ms)   select distinct @sql := concat('SELECT pb.name as unit,',group_concat(concat('SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =0 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS v',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =1 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS a',id,',SUM(CASE WHEN p.state =2 AND ce.id=',id,' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS n',id)),' FROM cia_ensures ce LEFT JOIN policies p on ce.id = p.cia_ensure_id INNER JOIN policy_business_units pb ON pb.id = p.policy_business_unit_id INNER JOIN comercial_areas ca ON ca.id = pb.comercial_area_id AND ca.id=1 Group by p.policy_business_unit_id') from cia_ensures where id in(1,2,3,4,5);
SQL (0.9ms)   prepare stmt from @sql;
SQL (0.2ms)   execute stmt;
```

Here is the view (is working fine and without problems but seems to be too long write several times the same code)

```
<table>
  <% @result3.each do |policy| %>
  <tr>
      <td><%= policy[0] %></td>
      <td><%= policy[1] %></td>
      <td><%= policy[2] %></td>
      <td><%= policy[3] %></td>
      <td><%= policy[4] %></td>
      <td><%= policy[5] %></td>
      ...
  </tr>
  <%end%> 
</table>
```

I tried to use inspect but it shows all the information in one td and not on each td:

```
<% @result3.each do |policy| %>
<tr>      
 <td align="center"><%= policy.inspect %></td>
</tr>
<%end%>
```

How can I do to show all this without writing lots of lines?

Is it possible to make this in one line? without writing <%= policy[#NUMBER] %>

Please somebody can help me with this?

I will really appreciate it.

Comment: Can you just inspect '@result3' and show the content?

Comment: Yes i tried but it shows all in one td and not in each td

Comment: Can't you use `each` on every policy object pretty much the same way you did with `@result3`?

Comment: Yes but what happen if I have 100 columns? thats a long code

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hmmm, might have missunderstood your question since it looks really simple, are you trying to shorten this?

Change:

```
<td><%= policy[0] %></td>
<td><%= policy[1] %></td>
<td><%= policy[2] %></td>
<td><%= policy[3] %></td>
<td><%= policy[4] %></td>
<td><%= policy[5] %></td>
```

To:

```
<% policy.each do |p| %>
  <td><%= p %></td>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 4):

Do this

```
  <% @result3.each do |policy| %>
  <tr>
      <% policy.each { |p| raw "<td>#{p}</td>" } %>
  </tr>
  <%end%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just iterate over each collection in each `policy` object.

```
<table>
  <% @result3.each do |policy| %>
      <tr>
          <%policy.each do |item| %>
              <td><%= item %></td>
          <%end%>
      </tr>
  <%end%> 
</table>
```